# Access denied Drive App when trying to delete file with app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am having exactly the same problem as
[Student Gradebook. Unable to complete script because of "Access denied: DriveApp"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45920379/student-gradebook-unable-to-complete-script-because-of-access-denied-driveapp)
and [Access denied Drive App when trying to delete file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44959149/access-denied-drive-app-when-trying-to-delete-file)

My code:

```
  // delete pdf if already exists
  var files = folder.getFilesByName(pdfName);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    files.next().setTrashed(true);
  };

  var theBlob = createblobpdf(sheetName, pdfName);
  var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);
  newFile.setShareableByEditors(true);  //to allow deletion of files not owned by yourself
  newFile.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
```

Example:
user A creates a PDF-file with the name 'filename.pdf' successfully with the code snippet above.
User B is supposed to overwrite that file by creating an updated version of 'filename.pdf', but this fails with the 'Access Denied' error described in the posts above.

```
 newFile.isShareableByEditors();
```

returns 'true'.

I have also tried:

```
  Utilities.sleep(1500);
```

All to no avail.

Anyone got a solution to this?

Comment: If you really want to delete the file you should use Drive API.  But since access was denied perhaps you should check with your admin

Comment: You cannot "overwrite" a file on figure drive. Just let user B to create the new file, and the old should be deleted by its owner, user A

Comment: @Cooper all users are able to delete the files manually in the google drive, so there is not a general auth problem.

Comment: And yet access was denied.

Comment: @GoranK you wrote 'You cannot "overwrite" a file on figure drive'. Are you aware of any documentation supporting this?

Comment: I haven't tired. Just a gues: try to delete the line: `newFile.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);` and add: `file.revokePermissions(Session.getActiveUser())` before trashing

Comment: @Cooper yes, the script fails exactly as described in the 2 earlier posts I refer to.

Comment: @Yuri Khristich  I can save your suggested code without erorrs but when I run it I get the execution error 'Invalid argument: file.owner'. You know why?

Comment: sorry for the autocorrect typo :), should be Google Drive, not figure drive. The thing is that unique file identifier on Google drive is a file ID, not a file title. That means if you create a new file with the same title as existing one, the original file will not be overwritten

Comment: *You know why?* nope :(

Comment: As a clumsy workaround you could create subfolder and try to move all unwanted files into this folder. Sweep them under the rug

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?