# convert a csv to google sheet and remove the csv file

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a code that converts a csv file to google sheet from a folder. What I would like to do is remove the csv file after conversion .Planning to make a script that runs each day and convert all the generated csv files to google sheet and remove the csv files with that name.
the Code I am using below

```
function convert_to_googlesheets() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1jxxxxxxxxWfl2yk4xxxxxxxx');
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    Drive.Files.copy({}, file.getId(), {convert: true});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add

```
file.setTrashed(true);
```

After `Drive.Files.copy({}, file.getId(), {convert: true});`

Comment: Thank you so much. It works like a charm . @Yuri Khristitch

Comment: Khristitch :is there a way to access a shared drive folder . I am using a shared drive and it throws an error stating no permission .

Comment: I'm not sure. I've read recently that there are problems with removing files from shared folders. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69001138/access-denied-drive-app-when-trying-to-delete-file-with-app-script