# App script to get File Info (from a Google Drive Folder), Rename Files, Edit Permission controlled from a google sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

## What the app script code below does:

1. `function DriveLinkFetcher` **lists file details** ("File url", "File name", "Viewers email", "Viewers names", "Editors email address", "Editors names", "Sharing Permission", "Sharing Access", "New file name", "Add new editors") of a google drive folder, given the url of the drive folder in cell "A2". The [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9Gpx.jpg) is a list  in a google sheet.
2. `function RenameDriveFiles` **renames "file names"** in the folder to "new file names" depending on user input in the "New file name" column.

---

## The problem:

**`function RenameDriveFiles`** works well for the files with no duplicate names. But if a file name has duplicates (for example, three "file 1", pls see the image) and I want to rename only the second file (rename to "file 100"), sometimes it renames all three files, sometimes two files.

The "File name" column contains duplicates and "File url" has unique IDs. So instead of using `fldr.getFilesByName(oldNames[i])`, is there a way to use `fldr.getFilesByURL(URL[i])`? Can you suggest any solution?

---

### The output sheet is like this:

[image: output sheet]

---

### The app script code:

```
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();


        function DriveLinkFetcher() {
          
.....
.....
        }
    
    
    function RenameDriveFiles() {
    
      var url=sh.getRange("A2").getValue(); //url input from user
      var fldrID=url.match(/[-\w]{25,}/);
      var fldr=DriveApp.getFolderById(fldrID);
      
      //var files=fldr.getFiles();
      
      var lr=sh.getLastRow()-6;
      var oldNames = [];
      var newNames = [];
    
      oldNames = sh.getRange(7, 2, lr).getValues();
      newNames = sh.getRange(7, 9, lr).getValues();
    
      
        for(var i = 0; i < oldNames.length ; i++){
    
          var myFileIterator = fldr.getFilesByName(oldNames[i]);
    
          while(myFileIterator.hasNext()){
            var currentFile = myFileIterator.next();
            currentFile.setName(newNames[i]);  
    
        }
      } 
    }
```

---

I know some VBA but this is my first attempt in app script. I am learning. Any help, any tip how to make this code better will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `var names=[],f,str;` is short for `var names=[]; var f; var str;` and the variable `str` was not even used, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Your question needs more focus.  Ask a specific question and provide a [mcve] that enables us to reproduce that specific problem.  We really don't want to have to debug your entire code.

Comment: @Yuri Khristich, thank you. Is there a short for `var oldNames = []; oldNames = sh.getRange(7, 2, lr).getValues();` ?

Comment: @Cooper, I have now edited to make it focused on a single problem.

Comment: As for the shorts, I'm not quite understand the question. The answer probably 'no', I see no shorter versions for these lines. But on the other hand you probably don't even need the array `oldNames` if you have 'links'. So the short variants are `''`, or something like that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have the list of URLs the task (to rename the files) becomes extremely simply and straightforward:

```
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();

function RenameDriveFiles() {

  var url      = sh.getRange("A2").getValue(); //url input from user
  var fldrID   = url.match(/[-\w]{25,}/);
  var fldr     = DriveApp.getFolderById(fldrID);
  var lr       = sh.getLastRow() - 6;
  var urls     = sh.getRange(7, 1, lr).getValues().flat();
  var ids      = urls.map(u => u.split('/')[5]);
  var newNames = sh.getRange(7, 9, lr).getValues().flat();

  for (var n in newNames) {
    if (newNames[n] != '') DriveApp.getFileById(ids[n]).setName(newNames[n]);
  }
}
```

You don't even need the old names.

But there could be [some problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69001138/access-denied-drive-app-when-trying-to-delete-file-with-app-script) with shared folders, actually.

**Update**

To add several editors from column 10 ('J'):

```
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();

function RenameDriveFiles() {

  var url      = sh.getRange("A2").getValue(); //url input from user
  var fldrID   = url.match(/[-\w]{25,}/);
  var fldr     = DriveApp.getFolderById(fldrID);
  var lr       = sh.getLastRow() - 6;
  var urls     = sh.getRange(7, 1, lr).getValues().flat();
  var ids      = urls.map(u => u.split('/')[5]);
  var newNames = sh.getRange(7, 9, lr).getValues().flat();
  var newEditors = sh.getRange(7, 10, lr).getValues().flat(); // column J

  for (var n in newNames) {
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(ids[n]);
    var editors = newEditors[n].split(',');
    if (newNames[n] != '') file.setName(newNames[n]);
    if (editors[0] != '') editors.forEach(ed => file.addEditor(ed));
  }
}
```

I haven't tried it, I hope it works.

Comment: Your solution is working like a charm. Thank you.

Can you please explain why have you used `.flat()`? 

I have added these lines:
`var newEditor = sh.getRange(7, 10, lr).getValues().flat();
  for (var n in newEditor) {
    if (newEditor[n] != '') DriveApp.getFileById(ids[n]).addEditor(newEditor[n]);
  }`
It works fine when there is one email address added as new editor. I want to add multiple editors separated with comma (example-editor1@gmail.com,editor2@gmail.com). Can you suggest a modification?

Comment: `array.fllat()` is a standard array's method. It changes an array this way: `[[1,2],[3,4]]` --> `[1,2,3,4]`. When you get values from several rows it's always a 2-d array: [[row1],[row2],[row3]]. If there is just one column and if you want to get the cells or the column you can do it this way: `[[row1],[row2],[row3]].flat()` --> `[row1,row2,row3]`

Comment: I've updated my answer with example how you can add the editors from next column.

Comment: It works fine when all the cells in column J contains email addresses. It does not work when there are empty cells in column J. I guess `if (newEditors[n] != '')` should be added. right?

Comment: For this particular case it would be enough just to check a first editor: `if (editors[0] !='') editors.forEach(ed => file.addEditor(ed));` I've updated my answer.

Comment: **Or** you can filter the array `editors` this way: `var editors = newEditors[n].split(',').filter(String)` it removes from array all empty elements.

Comment: I thank you from my heart for all the help you did.